# How to automatically set a Template Page Name next to a page in menu screen such as WooCommerce pages, front page, or posts page in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, page-template

When creating a menu, and after selecting a page as front page and another page as posts page..it appears next to the page in menu screen. For example, "Front Page" appears next to home page, and next to the blog page, the "Posts Page" appears, as well as the WooCommerce pages, Next to each page, the page type appears, such as Cart page, Account page, Shop page, etc..
How do I do this with a custom page template called- for example - "Services Page" ?

Comment: @moishy  ,  Unfortunately, my reputation does not allow me to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`display_post_states`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/display_post_states/) hook:

```
function custom_display_post_states( $states, $post ) {
    if ( 'Services' === $post->post_title ) {
        $post_states['custom-content'] = 'Services Page';
    }

    return $post_states;
}

add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'custom_display_post_states', 10, 2 );
```

or you can do by ID

```
if ( 1 === $post->ID) {
    $post_states['custom-content'] = 'Services Page';
}
```

To check if page has template:

```
function custom_display_post_states( $states, $post ) {
    $template = get_page_template_slug( $post->ID );
    
    if ( $template == 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_FILE' ) {
        $states['custom-content'] = 'Services Page';
    }

    return $states;
}

add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'custom_display_post_states', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest and response and apologies for the delay in replying, your code performs exactly the desired action but in two cases, if the user sets the page name "Services" or by a specific id that may change from user to user when using the theme, in fact I want this option to be public, What I mean is that if the user chooses to use the page as "Services Page Template" from Page Attributes, then the label next to the page name in the menu screen is page template name "Services Page" whatever the page name or id is , Hope to help me , Thank you,,,

Comment: I tried using "is_page_template" with some lines of your code but it didn't work, @Moishy

Comment: I updated my answer